# Qt QPainter Use of uninitialised value of size

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am developing under Ubuntu 16.04.
I did a simple QPainter call as

```
void microHUD::paintHUD(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if (isVisible())
    {
        // Update scaling factor
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(this);

                ...

        /*Draw all other text*/
        painter.setPen(_textPen);
        painter.setFont(_pfont);

        painter.drawText(_xCenterOffset * 0.8, -_yCenterOffset * 0.8, QString("%1").arg(_mav->getSatelliteCount()) + fixTypeStrings.at(_mav->getLocType()));
        painter.drawText(_xCenterOffset * 0.8, -_yCenterOffset * 0.8 + _fontPixSize, "Sat");

        ...
    }
}
```

But valgrind gives me the following error:

```
==4882== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x6458 with no size/direction hints.
==4882==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==4882==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==4882== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4882==    at 0x850299B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==4882==    by 0x8506636: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==4882==    by 0x85C59D4: __vsnprintf_chk (vsnprintf_chk.c:63)
==4882==    by 0x225C3CC6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x228ED75D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x22920726: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x22890E32: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x2288F900: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x228CB67B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x228916F5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x2289031B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x22890686: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x228E8BBC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x2267D7FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x2267DB1C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882==    by 0x4E7A40B: QGLTextureGlyphCache::resizeTextureData(int, int) (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x639F306: QTextureGlyphCache::fillInPendingGlyphs() (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x4E75DB6: ??? (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x4E7759C: QGL2PaintEngineEx::drawTextItem(QPointF const&, QTextItem const&) (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x63553F4: ??? (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x6355E6F: QPainter::drawText(QPointF const&, QString const&, int, int) (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1)
==4882==    by 0x44FAFE: QPainter::drawText(int, int, QString const&) (qpainter.h:883)
==4882==    by 0x4A86C3: microHUD::paintHUD(QPaintEvent*) (microHUD.cpp:216)
==4882==    by 0x4A787E: microHUD::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) (microHUD.cpp:138)
==4882==    by 0x58F8BD7: QWidget::event(QEvent*) (in /home/shupeng/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.6.1)
==4882==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4882==    at 0x2288F5A0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==4882== 
==4882== (action on error) vgdb me ...
```

What is the reason of this? Did I do anything wrong during QPainter calls?
Or is this a Qt/Linux issue that has nothing to do with my own code?

Comment: @Papipone False.

Comment: What are you painting over? QGLWidget? QOpenGLWIdget?

Comment: @Nyaruko One of your value is uninitialised. What's at line microHUD.cpp:216?

Comment: @Leherenn, it is just `painter.drawText(_xCenterOffset * 0.8, -_yCenterOffset * 0.8 + _fontPixSize, "Sat");` and I am very sure all the value are initialized in this line.

Comment: @Nyaruko Could you try to set the 3 of them at the start of the method with hardcoded values, and re-run Valgrind, just to be on the safe side?

Comment: Tried to hard set these values, nothing changes.